# Отправить только выбранные чекбоксы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {

    $("#ajax").load("1.php", "company="+$('input[name=checkbox1]:checkbox:checked').val()+"&mk="+$('input[name=checkbox2]:checkbox:checked').val());

    return true;

});
```

Если чек боксы не заданы/выбраны,  передает undefined, isset\empty не разпознают как пустую переменную. Необходимо не передавать не заданную группу чекбоксов.
т.е.

1. если выбран  checkbox1 передавать только его
2. если выбран  checkbox2 передавать только его
3. если выбраны оба то передавать оба

Либо если можно в PHP распознать переданый undefind, понимать что он не выбран.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выбора значений выбранных чекбоксов используйте is:

```
    $('SELECTOR').is(':checked').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на сколько корректно, но решил вопрос так:

```
                if ( $('input[name=checkbox1]:checkbox:checked').is(':checked')    ){                   
                string += "&company="+$('input[name=checkbox1]:checkbox:checked').val();
            }

            if ( $('input[name=checkbox2]:checkbox:checked').is(':checked')    ){                   
                string += "&mk="+$('input[name=checkbox2]:checkbox:checked').val();
            }


            alert(string);
        $("#ajax").load("1.php", string);
```